# how to label and refer subfigures under tabular environment?

Tags: floats, labels, ref

I have two subfigures and I need to refer them in text such as Fig. 1.1(a) and Fig. 1.1(a) using Fig. \ref{fig1.1a:chap1} and Fig. \ref{fig1.1b:chap1}. The output is not coming. Instead, a double question mark (Fig. ??) appears. How to resolve this?

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, oneside]{Thesis}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subfigure}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=125pt]{enrollment} \label{fig1.1a:chap1} \\[\abovecaptionskip]
        \small (a) Enrollment phase 
    \end{tabular}
    \vspace{\floatsep}
    \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=125pt]{verification} \label{fig1.1b:chap1} \\[\abovecaptionskip]
        \small (b) Verification phase 
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Mode of operations in a biometric authentication system}\label{fig1.1:chap1}%
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please add a full MWE, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`, with the needed packages.

Comment: @NBur Suggestions done.

Comment: package `subfigure is obsolete. use `subfig` insteadit or `subcaption` (which is more powerful). it load is not suficient, you should use its macro in table composition and than compile document at least twice.

Comment: @Zarko I am getting everything from it except the correct reference. ?? appears when I use \label and \ref.

Comment: @rudreshdwivedi, see my answer below. with your code you can't obtain what you expect.

Answer (score 4):

your approach to show two sub figures is at least unusual, frankly said wrong:

- you load obsolete package `subfigure` but than not use it. loading it is not sufficient, you should use its environment in figure composition and than compile document at least twice
- package `subfigure` is deprecated. use `subfig` instead it or `subcaption` (which is more powerful).
- references work on labels, which follows captions. that is not a case in your code example
- it is not clear, what is purpose of tables used in your images
- see if the following example works for you (i didn't use `thesis` document class, since i don't know which one you use. but this not influence on obtained result). after two compilation you will obtain working references

  ```
  \documentclass{report} % <--- instead of "thesis" which i haven't
  \usepackage{amsmath}
  \usepackage{graphicx}
  \usepackage{caption}
  \usepackage{subcaption} % <--- it is not compatible with "subfigure"
                          % with it you had to replace "subfigure"

  \usepackage{lipsum}     % <--- for dummy text

  \begin{document}
  \lipsum[1]
  \begin{figure}[htb]     % <---
      \centering
      \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.6\linewidth}     % <---
          \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
          \caption{Enrollment phase}          % <---
          \label{fig1.1a:chap1}
      \end{subfigure}                         % <---

      \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.6\linewidth}     % <---
          \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
          \caption{Verification phase}        % <---
          \label{fig1.1b:chap1}
      \end{subfigure}                         % <---
      \caption{Mode of operations in a biometric authentication system}
      \label{fig1.1:chap1}%
  \end{figure}
  Test of references: see subfigures \ref{fig1.1a:chap1}  and \ref{fig1.1b:chap1} in figure \ref{fig1.1:chap1}.
  \end{document}
  ```

[image]

with `% <---` are indicated changes in comparison to your document example. if you like to have wide images, than change width of `subfigure` to desired width.

**addendum:**

you may be lucky and will can use `subfigure` package ... :-) :

```
    \documentclass{report}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{caption}
    \usepackage{subfigure} % <---

    \usepackage{lipsum}

    \begin{document}
    \lipsum[1]
    \begin{figure}[htb]     % <---
        \centering
        \subfigure[Enrollment phase \label{fig1.1a:chap1}]%
        {
        \includegraphics[width=0.6\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
        } 

        \subfigure[Verification phase \label{fig1.1b:chap1}]%
        {
        \includegraphics[width=0.6\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
        }
        \caption{Mode of operations in a biometric authentication system}
        \label{fig1.1:chap1}%
    \end{figure}
    Test of references: see subfigures \ref{fig1.1a:chap1}  and \ref{fig1.1b:chap1} in figure \ref{fig1.1:chap1}.
    \end{document}
```

result is similar as before, however you may experienced new problems with it.

[image]

Comment: Error: Package subcaption Error: This package can't be used in cooperation(subcaption) with the subfigure package. \subcaption@CheckCompatibility

Comment: when you use `subcaption` in document, you need to delete `subfigure` from preamble!

Comment: how to delete that from preamble??

Comment: you could help from this \documentclass which I am using: https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/thesis/indian-institute-of-technology-kharagpur-(iit-kgp)-thesis-template

Comment: you go to *your* document. all after `\documentclass` and before ˙begin{document}` is preamble. somewhere in it is code line `usepackage{subfigure}` replace in it `subfigure` with `subcaption`. that is.

Comment: @Zarko The `Thesis` document class contains `\usepackage[...]{subfigure}`, so it's not in the preamble of the document itself.

Comment: @AxelSommerfeldt, it might be so. than i can't help to op. he should use better (more modern)  document class :-)

Comment: @Zarko I did that....still it did'nt work...same error...In thesis.cls, I commented \usepackage[scriptsize]{subfigure}, still the same error persist.

Comment: @rudreshdwivedi, do you test my mwe as it is? if it work, please than try again with `thesis` instead `report`. if with thesis will not work, than you can consider ˙thesis` as obsolete and you need to find more up-to-date document class or you try a luck and use `subfigure` environments from `subfigure` package. see addendum to my answer will appear asap)